# How to convert my array obtained from C++ to a 2D numpy array in Python without for loop

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I used `numpy C api` in C++ and got the following array in python:

```
>>> my_array
array([array([20211101., 20211101., 20211101., 20211101., 20211101.]),
       array([10601155, 10603088, 10603982, 10600983, 10603283], dtype=int32),
       array([30000011, 30000021, 30000031, 30000041, 30000051], dtype=int32),
       array([93003000., 93003000., 93003000., 93003000., 93003000.]),
       array([-1., -1., -1.,  1., -1.]),
       array([b'Sell', b'Sell', b'Sell', b'Buy', b'Sell'], dtype='|S4'),
       array([b'SQZ', b'SQZ', b'SQZ', b'SQZ', b'SQZ'], dtype='|S4'),
       array([ 100, 1100,  100,  200,  200], dtype=int32),
       array([34.19,  9.97, 29.46,  8.96, 27.85]),
      array([b'5', b'0', b'5', b'0', b'0'], dtype='|S4')], dtype=object)
```

The shape of this array is

```
>>> my_array.shape
(10,)
```

My purpose is to switch this array to a 2D numpy array and create a dataframe by `pd.DataFrame(data=my_array)`. But I failed to do it because I am supposed to input some numpy array like

```
np.array([[...],[...],[...],...])
```

not

```
array([array([...]),array([...]),array([...]),...])
```

I understand that I can use a for loop to get the dataframe, but the speed would be very slow if the dataset is large. So is there any method to convert my array to a real 2D numpy array and get a dataframe object?

Comment: can you try `df = pd.DataFrame(a.T)` asuming `a` the array?

Comment: @mozway it gives a dataframe that only has one column and 10 rows. Each row is an array

Comment: strange, I tried on the provided example and it gives me a shape (5,10)

Comment: @mozway So for my case, `df = pd.DataFrame(my_array.T)` and `df = pd.DataFrame(my_array)` give me the same (1, 10) result. Is this because each element of my array is also an array?

Comment: @mozway, the array is 1d, so `T` does nothing!

Comment: Since your subarrays vary in `dtype`, you don't want to create a 2d `numpy` array (with only one dtype).  I'm not that familiar with `pandas`, but isn't there are way of specifying a dataframe with a separate array or list for each column?

Comment: @hpaulj it's strange when I copied OP's example and evaluated it, this gave me a 2D array with shape `(10, 5)`, as I was busy I didn't looked in detail. Any idea why it could have automatically converted the array to 2D? The numpy version used was 1.21.5

Comment: @mozway, a simple copy-n-paste makes an array from a list of arrays.  If they are all the same shape, the result is 2-d array with single element objects (or as high a dimensional array as it can).  You have to use something like my example [135][136] to construct a 1d array containing the arrays.  If the subarrays vary in size you get the 1d array (and ragged array warning), but you shouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a list from your sample:

```
In [132]: alist
Out[132]: 
[array([20211101., 20211101., 20211101., 20211101., 20211101.]),
 array([10601155, 10603088, 10603982, 10600983, 10603283], dtype=int32),
 array([30000011, 30000021, 30000031, 30000041, 30000051], dtype=int32),
 array([93003000., 93003000., 93003000., 93003000., 93003000.]),
 array([-1., -1., -1.,  1., -1.]),
 array([b'Sell', b'Sell', b'Sell', b'Buy', b'Sell'], dtype='|S4'),
 array([b'SQZ', b'SQZ', b'SQZ', b'SQZ', b'SQZ'], dtype='|S4'),
 array([ 100, 1100,  100,  200,  200], dtype=int32),
 array([34.19,  9.97, 29.46,  8.96, 27.85]),
 array([b'5', b'0', b'5', b'0', b'0'], dtype='|S4')]
```

Using 'list transpose' to make a list of tuples, one per "row/record" of the frame:

```
In [133]: df = pd.DataFrame([tuple(x) for x in zip(*alist)])
In [134]: df
Out[134]: 
            0         1         2           3  ...       6     7      8     9
0  20211101.0  10601155  30000011  93003000.0  ...  b'SQZ'   100  34.19  b'5'
1  20211101.0  10603088  30000021  93003000.0  ...  b'SQZ'  1100   9.97  b'0'
2  20211101.0  10603982  30000031  93003000.0  ...  b'SQZ'   100  29.46  b'5'
3  20211101.0  10600983  30000041  93003000.0  ...  b'SQZ'   200   8.96  b'0'
4  20211101.0  10603283  30000051  93003000.0  ...  b'SQZ'   200  27.85  b'0'

[5 rows x 10 columns]
```

Since the subarrays are all the same length, making an object array from it requires some special handling.  We can't just copy-n-paste your display.

```
In [135]: arr = np.zeros(len(alist),object)
In [136]: arr[:] = alist
```

This makes a 1d array like yours, which will work as with the list

```
In [138]: df = pd.DataFrame([tuple(x) for x in zip(*arr)])
```

`pandas` may have another way of creating a frame with one column/series per array of a list, but this is best I can do from a `numpy` base.

Comment: yes lists work for me. Thank you!